# How to create a test class for apex that reads CSV file

Tags: apex, files, contentdocument, csv, base64

I was trying to test my apex class that gets a CSV file, reads it and creates actual records.

In my test class I tried to convert my CSV string into base64 string. Then I used this line of code `Blob fileBody = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(body);` in order to convert the String body to blob by decoding the base64 string.

Finally, passed it into a contentversion (attached to the object from where my apex reads the CSVs. However, on my query for this CSV within the class I am trying to test, the file type is 'UKNOWN'. The query is: `List<el_Bulk_Order_Process__c> bulkOrderList = [select id, el_Request_Type__c,(select id, title, FileType, ContentDocumentId from AttachedContentDocuments order by CreatedDate desc) from el_Bulk_Order_Process__c where id in: bulkOrderProcessIds];`

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating your test `ContentVersion`, you should define `PathOnClient` for `FileType` to be available.

Also no need to set `VersionData` with `EncodingUtil.base64Decode(body)`, it would be enough to just set it as `Blob.valueOf(body)`.

```
String OUTPUT_DOCUMENT_NAME = 'OUTPUT_DOCUMENT_NAME';
insert new ContentVersion(
    Title = OUTPUT_DOCUMENT_NAME, 
    PathOnClient = OUTPUT_DOCUMENT_NAME + '.csv', 
    VersionData = Blob.valueOf(body), 
    ContentLocation = 'S'
);
```